# How to create an ordenaded list of properties from agent in Netlogo?

Tags: list, netlogo

I have defined my turtles with the following.

```
turtles-own[val1, posx,posy,value]
```

And I have define globals called

xlist
   ylist
   vallist

That I start empty.
Now I want to create list that for any turtle have one value.

I did

```
to fillLists 
 set xlist lput posx xlist
 set ylist lput posy ylist
 set vallist lput value vallist
end
```

And this is called with:

```
 ask turtles[fillLists]
```

For example If I have 3 turtles with val1 be a name
Let's say we have:

```
t1 =[Mike, 1, 10, 100]
t2 =[Sasha, 2, 20, 200]
t3 =[Rocco, 3, 30, 300]
```

I would like to create list l1,l2,l3,l4.
Where the contents are:

```
l1= [Mike, Sasha, Rocco]
l2= [1,2,3]
l3= [10,20,30]
l4= [100,200,300].
```

But what i tried don't work. Because the list return empty.
What is happening, is some bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, so you may need to include more of the code where these commands are called. For example, if I run the `setup` as defined here:

```
globals [ nameslist xlist ylist vallist ]
turtles-own [ val1 posx posy value ]

to setup
  ca
  set nameslist []
  set xlist []
  set ylist []
  set vallist []

  crt 1 [ set val1 "Mike" set posx 1 set posy 10 set value 100 ]
  crt 1 [ set val1 "Sasha" set posx 2 set posy 20 set value 200 ]
  crt 1 [ set val1 "Rocco" set posx 3 set posy 30 set value 300 ]

  ask turtles [ fill-lists ]

  print nameslist
  print xlist
  print ylist
  print vallist  
  reset-ticks
end

to fill-lists
  set nameslist lput val1 nameslist
  set xlist lput posx xlist 
  set ylist lput posy ylist
  set vallist lput value vallist
end
```

I get an output like:

```
[Mike Rocco Sasha]
[1 3 2]
[10 30 20]
[100 300 200]
```

However, you may find that it's simpler to just use `of` to query the turtles for your variable of interest. For example the code below accomplishes more or less the same output, although its use may depend on your need:

```
turtles-own [ val1 posx posy value ]

to setup
  ca

  crt 1 [ set val1 "Mike" set posx 1 set posy 10 set value 100 ]
  crt 1 [ set val1 "Sasha" set posx 2 set posy 20 set value 200 ]
  crt 1 [ set val1 "Rocco" set posx 3 set posy 30 set value 300 ]

  print [val1] of turtles
  print [posx] of turtles
  print [posy] of turtles
  print [value] of turtles

  reset-ticks
end
```

Output:

```
[Sasha Mike Rocco]
[2 1 3]
[20 10 30]
[200 100 300]
```

Comment: Thank's, Could you check my new Netlogo Question.

Comment: @MariaGuthier - Sure, is it up yet?

Comment: It's now.Actually is a folllow up of this question. You were write that was not the real problem